# string to wstring in python

Tags: python, string, sockets, wstring

I have a udp socket which received datagram of different length. 
The first of the datagram specifies what type of data it is going to receive say for example 64-means bool false, 65-means bool true, 66-means sint, 67-means int and so on. As most of datatypes have known length, but when it comes to string and wstring, the first byte says 85-means string, next 2 bytes says string length followed by actual string. For wstring 85, next 2 bytes says wstring length, followed by actual wstring.

To parse the above kind off wstring format `b'U\x00\x07\x00C\x00o\x00u\x00p\x00o\x00n\x001'` I used the following code

```
data = str(rawdata[3:]).split("\\x00")
data = "".join(data[1:])
data = "".join(data[:-1])
```

Is this correct or any other simple way?

As I received the datagram, I need to send the datagram also. But I donot know how to create the datagrams as the socket.sendto requires `bytes`. If I try to convert string to `utf-16` format will it covert to wstring. If so how would I add the rest of the information into `bytes`

From the above datagram information `U`-85 which is wstring, `\x00\x07` - 7 length of the wstring data, `\x00C\x00o\x00u\x00p\x00o\x00n\x001` - is the actual string `Coupon1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complete answer depends on exactly what you intend to do with the resulting data. Splitting the string with `'\x00'` (assuming that's what you meant to do? not sure I understand why there are two backslashes there) doesn't really make sense. The reason for using a `wstring` type in the first place is to be able to represent characters that aren't plain old 8-bit (really 7-bit) ascii. If you have any characters that aren't standard Roman characters, they may well have something other than a zero byte separating the characters in which case your `split` result will make no sense.

Caveat: Since you mentioned `sendto` requiring bytes, I assume you're using python3. Details will be slightly different under python2.

Anyway if I understand what it is you're meaning to do, the "utf-16-be" codec may be what you're looking for. (The "utf-16" codec puts a "byte order marker" at the beginning of the encoded string which you probably don't want; "utf-16-be" just puts the big-endian 16-bit chars into the byte string.) Decoding could be performed something like this:

```
rawdata = b'U\x00\x07\x00C\x00o\x00u\x00p\x00o\x00n\x001'

dtype = rawdata[0]
if dtype == 85:        # wstring
    dlen = ord(rawdata[1:3].decode('utf-16-be'))
    data = rawdata[3: (dlen * 2) + 3]
    dstring = data.decode('utf-16-be')
```

This will leave `dstring` as a python unicode string. In python3, all strings are unicode. So you're done.

Encoding it could be done something like this:

```
tosend = 'Coupon1'
snd_data = bytearray([85])  # wstring indicator
snd_data += bytearray([(len(tosend) >> 8), (len(tosend) & 0xff)])
snd_data += tosend.encode('utf-16-be')
```